# Where is the denoise option in 2.90?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

I was using the denoise option in Blender 2.8, but cant seem to find it in 2.90. The documentation refers to the "Render Layers" but it doesn't seem to be there either.

[image]

When I open an older project that was created with 2.8 in 2.9, the denoise option is there and works fine.

is there a setting i need to check to enable the feature by default in new files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The denoiser options are in the Properties Window > Render settings > Sampling > Denoising.

[image]

You can choose what kind of denoiser to use.

[image]

**NLM** is the original denoiser (native non-local denoiser), that runs on any computing device.

**OpenImageDenoiser** is Intel Open Image Denoiser, that runs on CPU

In this section you can enable the **viewport denoising** as well.